# How to add a vertical-tile (only) background to an Android app

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, background

It's very simple to repeat horizontally and vertically the background of a linear layout in a Android's app. You simply need to use tileMode (see [How to make android app's background image repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706913/how-to-make-android-apps-background-image-repeat))

However tileMode in xml file doesn't allow me to repeat the background image only in vertical axis. There's a tileModeY but you cannot access it from xml.

I'm trying to modify that property to "repeat".

I've a main.xml file with the linear layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
              android:id="@+id/mainMenuLayout" 
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

I've a image in drawable/welcomebackground.png and also a xml file for the image in drawable/welcomebackgroundpattern.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/welcomebackground"
        android:dither="true" />
```

In my activity I've tried this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Resources res = getResources();
    BitmapDrawable background = (BitmapDrawable) res.getDrawable(R.drawable.welcomebackground);
    background.setTileModeY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
    (new View(this)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.welcomebackground);
    }
```

But my background is still all black. Of course I'm able to add it from the xml but it's repeated in both x and y axis.

So my question is quite simple: how can I repeat vertically "welcomebackground" image in my activity?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Bitmap Tile on X Only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657793/android-bitmap-tile-on-x-only)

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution: [Android Bitmap Tile on X Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657793/android-bitmap-tile-on-x-only)