# Tiling a Bitmap on a Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, tiling

I would like to create a 'graph paper' look to the Bitmap I am drawing via a Canvas, and trying to figure out the best way to do this.

I can't pass a source Bitmap containing the graph paper background to the Canvas constructor, as I am getting the Canvas in a SurfaceView via the .lockCanvas() call.

Some solutions I've tried:

- I've tried implementing [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311042/android-tile-bitmap/4575738#4575738) in my SurfaceView's Thread.run(), but the issue I believe is when the BitmapDrawable is converted to a Bitmap... it loses the tiling properties.

  canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
  BitmapDrawable TileMe = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.editor_graph));
  TileMe.setTileModeX(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
  TileMe.setTileModeY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);

  Bitmap b = TileMe.getBitmap();
  canvas.drawBitmap(b, 0, 0, null);
- If I use the [Canvas.drawBitmap method that takes a destination RectF as a parameter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.RectF,%20android.graphics.Paint%29), it looks like the bitmap will be tiled to fill the RectF... but how do I declare a RectF reliably that fills the entire view area?
- Setting the Activities background to the desired graph paper look also doesn't work, as the bitmap/canvas layout is opaque and blocks that from being seen.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have two easy solutions:

- Either use a BitmapDrawable, but instead of extracting the Bitmap, just call BitmapDrawable.draw(Canvas). Don't forget to set the drawable's bounds to fill your drawing area.
- Create a Paint with a BitmapShader and draw a rectangle with it (this is basically what BitmapDrawable does).

Comment: Used the BitmapDrawable.draw(Canvas) method, works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Maybe woth noting that you have to set myBitmapDrawable.setTileModeX(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
and myBitmapDrawable.setTileModeY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT); to actually  draw it tiled...

Answer (score -3):

I'm sure there is a way to get a tiled effect using a `SurfaceView`.  Unfortunately, it looks like you can't use the `BitmapDrawable` with a canvas.  So you would probably have to implement you own custom tiling method by creating your own series of `Rect`'s on the `Canvas` and drawing a scaled bitmap to each one.

It honestly wouldn't be that hard.  Just get the width/height of the view, and create an array of `Rect`'s based on this data that you will draw the `Bitmap` to.

Alternatively, if you don't need to make modifications to the actual tiled background on the fly, just draw it as a background and draw the `SurfaceView` on top of it.  That post you linked provided multiple solutions to tiling a `BitmapDrawable` that you could implement.

Comment: You can use BitmapDrawable with a Canvas. All you have to do is write theDrawable.draw(canvas).