# Repeat drawable in imageview?

Tags: android, imageview, drawable, tile

Is it possible to repeat a drawable in an ImageView? I manage to repeat my drawable as a divider in a ListView, but not as an ImageView. Here is my repeated image definition:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/xdividerrepeat" android:tileMode="repeat"/>
```

Thanks
Markus

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could use a "dummy" view like a LinearLayout to accomplish this. Just create a LinearLayout with the size you need and set its background drawable to be your repeating bitmap.

See [Android Tile Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311042/android-tile-bitmap).

Answer (score 31):

Yes it's possible. You just need to specify the scale type of the `ImageView`. Without it the `<bitmap>` is just scaled.

```
<ImageView
    ...
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    ...
/>
```

Comment: Works for me, so could you explain me technically why?

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be an ImageView?  When I want this kind of functionality, I use a container like LinearLayout and just use my BitmapDrawable as in your example as the background.  Since the "background" attribute is inherited from View, if you don't need any more functionality than to display a repeating image, you can just use a View in your xml layout.

Comment: what if you want to keep the bitmap's original size?