# ImageView with bitmaps downloaded from URL (repeat tile mode)

Tags: android, universal-image-loader, picasso

Is there any easy way to tile bitmap downloaded from URL on ImageView?

Preferably using Picasso or UniversalImageLoader.

I was thinking about getting image from Picasso cache and draw on canvas, but maybe there is more elegant way?

Thanks,
Bartek.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Repeat drawable in imageview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159484/repeat-drawable-in-imageview)

Comment: I've seen that. It does work perfect for "static" drawables, but how to show tiled image downloaded from URL?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did with Glide 4.0:

```
 Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load(url).into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
      @Override
      public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Transition<? super      Bitmap> transition) {
           BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), resource);
           bitmapDrawable.setTileModeX(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
           bitmapDrawable.setTileModeY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
           myImageView.setBackground(bitmapDrawable);
        }
 });
```