# how to show dotted border to table layout

Tags: android, tablelayout

I am new in android, want to show border in tablelayout.

can any one please help me, it is very critical for me.

Answer (score 5):

Try setting a [`ShapeDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) as the background of the elements you want a border on. You can define a ShapeDrawable in an XML file in your res/drawables folder. In particular, the `stroke` element has the `dashWidth` and `dashGaps` parameters that let you make a dashed line:

```
<stroke
    android:width="integer"
    android:color="color"
    android:dashWidth="integer"
    android:dashGap="integer" />
```

You can also just set a repeating dots image as the background of the entire table, then set a solid background and margin on the cells (see [this trick](http://www.droidnova.com/display-borders-in-tablelayout,112.html), which is written about solid borders but I'm sure you can fake with a 2x2 [repeating bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311042/android-tile-bitmap) of a checkerboard pattern).

Comment: I have implemented shape with button ... but i am not able to show border in table layout
1) coupon_detail_table
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#2D3C2D" android:dashWidth="10dip" android:dashGap="6dip" />
</shape> 

<TableLayout android:background="@drawable/coupon_detail_table">

i don't know why it is not working

Comment: You can't just jam the shape drawable in the layout file - you need to define it in its own XML file in the drawables folder, then set that drawable as the `android:background` of the View in the layout that you want. See the Graphics/Drawables demos and related XML files in the ApiDemos app to get a feel for how that works (http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html)