# How to create a resizable cross hatched drawable in Android

Tags: android, graphics, drawable, nine-patch

I would like to be able to apply a cross hatch as the background of a row in a table. I do not think you can create a cross hatch effect as a 9-patch. Does anyone know another way to get this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a repeatable tile image of the desired pattern, and repeat it in the background. The code to accomplish this can be found in answers to this question - [Android Tile Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311042/android-tile-bitmap)