# Android Tile Bitmap and 9path

Tags: android, bitmap, nine-patch

Good solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4575738/876077, but it not worked with 9path. How I can set tile mode by X *AND* stretch my bitmap.9.png vertically?

Answer (score 1):

9-patches don't support tiling at the moment. They are only meant to be stretched.

Comment: ok, thanks. and how I can to set the long image with partly scaling?

Comment: @monyag I think you should start a new question of itself instead of asking in a comment. Then, you can place a link to that newly created question here.