# Layout: dynamic background

Tags: android, android-layout, background

I'm creating app similar to this:

[image]

Width of one hour is expressed in dp. How can I create such divided (by borders or by different colors) background? I though about inserting ImageViews but is there better method?
Currently my layout:

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tableLayout" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/tableRowLayout1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/tableRowLayout2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

And I insert elements to relative layouts.

Thanks for help.

**SOLUTION**

```
    HorizontalScrollView mainView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView1);

    Point size = new Point();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);

    int height = size.y;
    int width = dpToPixels(dpPerHour);

    Bitmap bmpBg = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.schedule_bg)).getBitmap();
    Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmpBg, width, height, true);
    BitmapDrawable viewBg = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), scaled);
    viewBg.setTileModeX(TileMode.REPEAT);
    viewBg.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    mainView.setBackground(viewBg);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For the horizontally separated white areas

You can use a `<bitmap>` with tiling via `android:tileMode="repeat"` (one example of bitmap constructed via [tiling the source drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1312213/1337257)).

You could tile a `<shape>` inside of the `<bitmap>` with a bit of work. But, I suspect tiling an image drawable inside the `<bitmap>` is easier.

### For the buttons

You might want to look into using 9-patches to specify the appearance of the buttons. You can use 9-patches to make every button have a thin black border. Or, you could use a `<shape>` drawable.

Comment: I mean the white background divided horizontally.

Comment: Almost perfect. But width of one hour is expressed in dp. Can I scale source drawable in runtime?

Comment: This scaling should be effortless on your part if you intend to maintain the same aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

if you give your `LinearLayout` a black background color, then you only need to put

```
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
```

or some such amount into each of your `RelativeLayout` rows, and the `LinearLayout` will show through in those areas, and look like what I see in your example.

Alternately, If you want one item on each row that doesn't show the `marginTop` and `marginBottom`, like those colored buttons on the left, then make those views a bit taller than the ones on the right, make the `RelativeLayouts` have a gravity that centers vertically, and you will see the black above and below the shorter views.

Comment: I mean the white background divided horizontally.