# How to repeat image backgroung LinearLayout horizontal and vertical?

Tags: android

How to repeat image backgroung LinearLayout horizontal and vertical?

```
<LinearLayout ...
              android:background="@drawable/my_image" >
<LinearLayout/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `tileMode` property with a `Bitmap` drawable. There's an example in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311042/android-tile-bitmap)

Answer (score 0):

Try this backrepeat.xml should look like:

```
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/tile"
    android:tileMode="repeat"
    android:dither="true" />
```